# How to implement nested WHEN statements in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

First things first apologise if such a question already exist but I couldn't find anything relevant to my case.

I want to implement nested `WHEN` statements in the `SELECT` statement. The logic is when `order_1` is equal to 0, do the next check if `next` is equal to 0 too. If so, return a boolean of the result `order_1 - 5 = order_2`. Otherwise, assign to `order_1` the value of `next`

Now in form of the query...

`CASE WHEN order_1 = 0 WHEN next = 0 THEN order_1 - 5 = order_2 ELSE order_1 = next AS is_combined`

Comment: you can use nested case  for eg.

````select case when 1 = 1 then (case when 2 = 2 then "1=1 and 2=2" end )
            when 3 = 3 then (case when 4 = 4 then "3=3 and 4=4" end )
            end as nested_case````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a nested statement for that:

```
CASE WHEN order_1 = 0 and next = 0 THEN order_1 - 5 = order_2 ELSE order_1 = next AS is_combined
```

but if you want a nested when statement write like this

```
SELECT gameNumber FROM `bigquery-public-data.baseball.schedules`
where 
case when year=2016 then (case when type='REG' then duration_minutes=duration_minutes end) else null end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add and AND to join the conditions:

```sql
CASE WHEN order_1 = 0 AND next = 0 
     THEN order_1 - 5 = order_2 
     ELSE order_1 = next AS is_combined
```